# Is there a tool to generate layer 2 multicast traffic for test

Tags: linux, networking, multicast

Is there a tool to generate **layer 2 multicast** traffic on Linux (debian/raspberry/ubuntu). Need it for testing purpose. Need to monitor some netfilter rules. Expecting no one on the other side to listen to this traffic or send any response. Just that the traffic should reach the destination. I believe NIC accepts Layer 2 multicast traffic without any additional config, so tcpdump and wireshark will be able to sniff the traffic on the listening host. Or maybe wireshark converts NIC to promiscuous mode which enables to sniff multicast traffic.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The man page for `socat` has this example:

```
$ socat - UDP4-DATAGRAM:224.255.0.1:6666,bind=:6666,ip-add-membership=224.255.0.1:eth0
```

which gives me sufficiently ok-looking tcpdump output (though I only tested this on the same machine):

```
19:23:47.218608 00:11:22:33:44:55 > 01:00:5e:7f:00:01, 
    ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 51: 
    192.02.1.6666 > 224.255.0.1.6666: UDP, length 9
```

Though the netcat I have also seems to work (`nc.openbsd`):

```
$ nc -u 224.255.0.1 6666
```

Both read from stdin.